# MySQL counting cycles in data range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

- My MySQL table is filled up by a potentiometer, a hardware.
- As values of the sensor change data is added to the MySQL table column named Pot.
- Pot is the column which contains the values being read from the potentiometer as time goes on.
- The values in this column range from 760 to 1007.
- The values in this column cannot instantly jump from 760 to 1007, it has to be continuous.

So here is what the table is like:

```
    ***Pot***
Time 1s -> 1007
Time 2s -> 987
Time 3s -> 909
Time 4s -> 887
time 5s -> 779
Time 6s -> 775
Time 7s -> 767
Time 8s -> 1004
Time 9s -> 1004
Time 10s -> 1004
Time 11s -> 1001
Time 12s -> 987
Time 13s -> 899
```

The time arrows I have added are to show that at time 1 second a value is added by the hardware, time 2 second 987 is added....at 7seconds after experiment started 767 is added.

Once the lower value is reached, the sensor starts entering the values near the upper bound like 1007 and such. From the high value, the sensor starts entering values back towards the lower bound again. There may be duplicates but as you can see rows are entered as time passes.

**What I want to do is find out how many times from upper bound to lower bound the sensor's values went.**

So in this case the output for number of cycles would be 1 and not 2 because the values have not yet reached 760ish to be considered 2 cycles.

```
select count(*)
from (select cycle, min(BBQ_Chicken) as minpot, maxpot as maxpot
      from (select *,
                   @cycle = if(pot >= 1000 and @state = 'bottom',
                               if(@state := 'top', @cycle + 1, @cycle + 1),
                               if(pot < 770, if(@state := 'bottom', @cycle, @cycle), @cycle)
                              ) as cycle
            from `SeInfo` t cross join
                 (select @state := 'bottom', @cyclestart) vars
            order by id
           ) p
     ) t
where minpot < 770 and maxpot >= 1000;
```

The above code doesn't return any rows when I run the query...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a state machine to keep track of whether something has most recently hit the top or bottom of the range.  You can then use transitions to the top to measure when a cycle begins.  The following gets summary information about the cycles:

```
select cycle, min(pot+0) as minpot, max(pot+0) as maxpot
from (select si.*,
             @cycle := if(pot >= 1000 and @state = 'bottom',
                          if(@state := 'top', @cycle + 1, @cycle + 1),
                          if(pot < 770, if(@state := 'bottom', @cycle, @cycle), @cycle)
                         ) as cycle
      from SeInfo si cross join
           (select @state := 'bottom', @cycle := 0) vars
      order by id
     ) si
group by cycle;
```

You can use this as a subquery to get the number that meet your conditions:

```
select count(*)
from (select cycle, min(pot+0) as minpot, max(pot+0) as maxpot
      from (select si.*,
                   @cycle := if(pot >= 1000 and @state = 'bottom',
                                if(@state := 'top', @cycle + 1, @cycle + 1),
                                if(pot < 770, if(@state := 'bottom', @cycle, @cycle), @cycle)
                               ) as cycle
            from SeInfo si cross join
                 (select @state := 'bottom', @cycle := 0) vars
            order by id
           ) si
      group by cycle
     ) si
where minpot < 770 and maxpot >= 1000;
```

Note that this assumes that you have a column that specifies the ordering of the values.  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so you need a column to specify the ordering.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89c812/4) is the SQL Fiddle with it working.

Comment: I have a column named id which does increment by 1 for each entry so it creates ordering. I have very unfamiliar with the syntax. What do I need in my database to run that code? I have 2 columns named, pot, id.

Comment: Can you please help? Your code isn't working after I made some corrections in it... It isn't working because there are syntax errors and I am not sure what is going on in the code so I just tried to change it to rename it to my column names and table name but it isn't working so please have a look.

Comment: @OmarKhawaja . . . I fixed the obvious syntax problems.  If you put up a SQL Fiddle, then we can get it to work on your actual data structure.

Comment: I am unable to enter any data into the SQL Fiddle because it gives some error but I created the schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c757c/4

Comment: Error says: DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.

It probably means I cannot insert data to that SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @OmarKhawaja . . . The `insert` goes on the left side (along with the `create`).  See the SQL Fiddle in my revised answer for an example.  (That is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89c812/4.)

Comment: ...I ran the code after your edit and now I get this result: 

 cycle  minpot  maxpot
0  147  999
1  0  1000

Comment: @OmarKhawaja . . . Sometimes the distance from the idea to the implementation is longer than one would like.